# JavaFX performance difference FXML component vs Controller component

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, styling

I'm Developing a mobile application, performance is one of the main factor that i need to consider while coding.I was curious about different ways to create UI elements in JavaFX and how they would stack up when it comes to performance.

**Different ways to create UI elements can be categorized into below 2 categories**.

1. Defining elements in FXML

   ```
   <Button fx:id="buttonhere"  styleClass="Button" text="Button" textAlignment="CENTER" />
   ```

This seems to be popular way of defining UI elements in JavaFX. style can be assigned to them in controller or set CSS to control them.

2. Defining Elements in Controller

   ```
    Button btn = new Button();
   ```

**New UI elements can be created in controller directly.**

Defining styling again can be done at 3 different places

- Controller level:

  ```
  component.setStyle("-fx-style:");
  ```
- With CSS

  ```
  .componentTag{ -fx-style:}
  ```
- At FXML level where we can control some aspects

I want to understand which combination of the above list provides maximum performance gain and should be used whenever possible, or if there is any performance difference at all.

Comment: In your question you seem to assume that creating objects from fxml is fundamentally different than creating an objects from java code. It is not. Everything created from a fxml can be created from java code faster. I don't know if *At FXML level where we can control some aspects* means setting the appropriate properties of the nodes instread of using css, but that case it should be more performant. Using inline styles vs using a css stylesheet both has drawbacks. The css stylesheet needs to be parsed only once in contrast to applying the same inline style to multiple nodes.

Comment: But with a CSS stylesheet JavaFX needs to figure out which nodes to apply the style too and which rule to use, if there are multiple conflicting rules. You don't need to do this for inline style...

Comment: I could be wrong, but would there be any performance difference at all since both methods are basically compiled into the same output anyway?

Comment: All the methods described above are essentially same and produces exact same result. what i'm interested is to see if there is any performance advantage in using one over another.